# Flutter/Dart: Equivalent of "substring" for integers

Tags: flutter, dart

What would be the equivalent of substring for integers in Dart? For example:

```
int 123456;

result1 = 123;
result2 = 456;
```

I've gotten this far, but now I'm stuck:

```
int 123456;

int result1 = ??
int result2 = 123456 % 1000; // 456
```

Comment: `int result1 = 123456 ~/ 1000;`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!